# How can I collect field values from my view if I don't have a BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that does not have a BeginForm and I’d like to collect the values from dropdown lists and fields and send them off to a controller to perform a query.   I would like to use some type of button to send the parameters to the controller.

Questions: Should I wrap the fields of my view in a BeginForm so that I can use an  ?

Can I use FormCollection or something similar that does not require a BeginForm?

How can I get the values from the fields of my view and pass them to a controller as parameters?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Id just wrap them in a form. Form elements belong in a form.

Either that or use JavaScript on every element and do an Ajax request to the controller. Perhaps looking at Knockout to manage the process.

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend to have a HTML form in those cases. If you are creating using `Html.BeginForm` or directly putting the form element that's upto you though I recommend the earlier one.

```
Can I use FormCollection or something similar that does not require a BeginForm?
```

To use `FormCollection` in the action parameter it's not mandatory to use `BeginForm` or even have a form in the view. Using jquery you can can easily collect the fields based upon their id or name and you can use `$.post` to make a post request and still you can use the formcollection in the action. Instead of using `FormCollection` if possible you have to create an view model and use it.

> How can I get the values from the fields of my view and pass them to a
>   controller as parameters?

If you are not using form then you have collect each field value using "id" for ex. $("#ddlCity"), form a json object and you can use the jquery's [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method.